# TypeScript parameter type is a union of multiple types: How can I determine which was supplied and work with it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeguards

I'm working with the [React Google Login](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login) library in TypeScript.  It has type bindings for TypeScript, but all the examples are in JavaScript, and I am pretty new to TypeScript.

The setup code looks like this:

```
  <GoogleLogin
    clientId="client-id-value"
    onSuccess={successResponseGoogle}
    onFailure={failureResponseGoogle}
    cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
  />
```

In TypeScript, the signature for the onSuccess callback is:

```
readonly onSuccess: (response: GoogleLoginResponse | GoogleLoginResponseOffline) => void
```

The `GoogleLoginResponseOffline` type has only one property, `code`, where `GoogleLoginResponse` has a range of properties to access the details of the authenticated user.

The problem that I am having is that TypeScript will not let me access any of the GoogleLoginResponse properties on the response parameter, saying, for example

> *"Property 'getBasicProfile' does not exist on type GoogleLoginResponseOffline'"*

I have tried the following to cast or check the type of the parameter, but all give errors of one type or another.  My function looks like this:

```
const responseGoogleSuccess = (response: GoogleLoginResponse|GoogleLoginResponseOffline) => {

  // Tried to check for property to identify type
  if(response.googleId){    // Property 'googleId' does not exist on type 'GoogleLoginResponseOffline'
      const profile = response.getBasicProfile();  // Property 'getBasicProfile' does not exist on type 'GoogleLoginResponseOffline'
  }

  // Tried to cast like this
  const typedResponse = <GoogleLoginResponse>response;

  // Tried to check type
  if(response instanceof GoogleLoginResponse){   // 'GoogleLoginResponse' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
  }
}
```

It looks from the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards) as if the `if(response instanceof GoogleLoginResponse)` is close, fails in this case because `GoogleLoginResponse` is an interface and it needs to be a class.

Please tell me how this is done!  I've looked at lots of StackOverflow questions with similar titles, but none cover this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `in` operator to [narrow the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator):

> For a `n in x` expression, where `n` is a string literal or string literal type and `x` is a union type, the “true” branch narrows to types which have an optional or required property `n`, and the “false” branch narrows to types which have an optional or missing property `n`

```
const responseGoogleSuccess = (response: GoogleLoginResponse | GoogleLoginResponseOffline) => {
  if('googleId' in response) {
      const profile = response.getBasicProfile(); // response is of type GoogleLoginResponse here
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA4g9nA5gGwgGSQSwHYCUIDOYc2B0AvFAN5SIIoQCSAJgFxQHABOOiANLQjAAQgEMCmAMYAFLnABmmVOwAUASijkAfNSjZRAWwjtOPbIigBfKwFgAUPdCRY9VBkQ58REmQDy8+WQcCl1JOGZjDm5eKwBue3sw0mAoLkJiUgh4JFQAZQBXSUlCAk0oFTTvTPZshndPdJ9oAB8XHPQsPEbM-0DgjW1qeygoTHlygHI6dpYJ0exU7rINKmGRqCTOKDA5RVQyyoyyADpEITEJGV2lCHV4uxHLe0sgA)

---

You could of course define [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), but using `in` operator is much easier in this case. But if you need this in several places this is how type guard can be defined:

```
type Reposense = GoogleLoginResponse | GoogleLoginResponseOffline;

const responseGoogleSuccess = (response: Reposense) => {
  if (isLoginResponse(response)) {
    const profile = response.getBasicProfile();
  }
}

const isLoginResponse = (response: Reposense): response is GoogleLoginResponse =>
  'googleId' in response;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4g9nA5gGwgGSQSwHYCUIDOYc2B0AvFAN5SIIoQCSAJgFxQHABOOiANLQjAAQgEMCmAMYAFLnABmmVOwAUASijkAfNSjZRAWwjtOPbIigBfKwFgAUPdCRY9VBkQ58REmQDy8%20WQcCl1JOGZjDm5eKwBue0dwaHxiMlIQ%20CQ3LDxCYnSoAB8XLPQcr3y-AKDsCHiHOzDSYCguPJ8ITIYAZQBXSUlCAk0oFTbvdPYUuDSyDW1qeygoTHlRzAJ3T3b0sZ25jSol5agmzigwOUVUEfHKiAA6RCExCRkrpQh1euXLez%20GmcWhstrkJmQRntwZFprMIGp2HcOithl1sh4wfdNFpjgByOilFi4lbYVr7OpAA)

Comment: Thanks, I tried out all the options and this was the most concise way to achieve what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a user defined type guard: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards.

In you case you will check the type based on the content of the object coming at run time and not based on its structure which is the before mentioned interface

```js
function isGoogleLoginResponse(response: GoogleLoginResponse|GoogleLoginResponseOffline): response is GoogleLoginResponse {
    // you can check more properties here off course
    return (response as GoogleLoginResponse).googleId !== undefined; 
}
```

With this in place, you can use the function in a `if` condition, then inside the `if` you can use the response object as `GoogleLoginResponse` typescript will understand that.

Comment: Thank you, this answer also works.  I liked this answer because it's explicit; and would use it if I needed to do the check in many places.  But for a single usage it's a lot more code that the response I selected as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a type assertion, e.g.

```
const responseGoogleSuccess = (response: GoogleLoginResponse|GoogleLoginResponseOffline) => {

  if((response as GoogleLoginResponse).googleId){   
    // do something with (response as GoogleLoginResponse).googleId
  }
}
```

[Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=13&ssc=69&pln=12&pc=1#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkAiUAOUwAmUSAngAowD2OAzqgN7CrOo2UC2UEAFuAOYAuVGACu7AEaxgAX2BQAHjkowIqCCTyoAggBsdFanQC8qABQBZclVqoAZBmx5CxK4YCUqAD6oAbpRAEANzAoJCwiCiolgY2jMwEIDQI4jpQAMLI3FBC4pSUqQhgwbLAcCJgSBAglGCoBJQAKllN-KY41jRCuvodHoxMqCBwZmoaUJRwpm0dqAh00b0AdAlJKemZUG4AhEZGAOTlRHDgUAR7qG4DSDVsqYs6lHxT7Yaz8660bsuJyakZSFk3MVgPUmlAWmAnvQ6j81v8skJEDoaFAADSsDhcXiQgQARmkbiAA)

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get this to work - still got the TypeScript error *Property 'getBasicProfile' does not exist on type 'GoogleLoginResponseOffline'* withing the if block.

Comment: you said "The GoogleLoginResponseOffline type has only one property, code". So you would need to add an else clause above to handle the other type `GoogleLoginResponseOffline`